# opening quick assist with web link

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

just starting my career in coding and want to know if opening quick assist which is a default desktop application in Windows could be opened from a web link.

p a href="ms-photos:viewer?" target="_blank" role="button" class="ocpExternalLink supLinkButton x-hidden-focus" ms.cmpgrp="content" ms.pgarea="Body">Change product key in Settings

html

the above code allows me to view product key in settings, open the setting, photos and other default applications. via a chrome prompt.

I would like to do the same with quick assist application to open up via a link attached to my company website page.

kindest regards, rex

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can open it with: `ms-quick-assist://` so just edit your href in your anchor tag.

For example:   `<a href="ms-quick-assist://">Open Quick Assist</a>`